# React-native: how to render inputs based on a number selected on a previous screen and be able to store the inputs

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-native-flatlist

I have a screen where the user selects the number of players for a game:

[image]

On the next screen, some text inputs appear and I want to be able to name the players so these names can be stored in a database:

[image]

I am using a FlatList to generate these fields, but it seems that I can't use the onChangeText here. If I try to input text into any of the fields I get this error:

[image]

This is the code:

```js
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {View, Text, StyleSheet, ScrollView, Image, FlatList} from 'react-native';
import colors from '../config/colors';
import {TextField} from '../components/TextField';
import {PrimaryButton} from '../components/PrimaryButton';
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-community/async-storage';

class player_names_screen extends Component {
    constructor (props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            num_players: [],
            Player1: '',
            Player2: '',
            Player3: '',
            Player4: '',
            Player5: '',
            Player6: '',
            Player7: '',
            Player8: ''
        }
    }

    componentDidMount = () => {
        this.getNumPlayers();
    }
    
    //This is my nasty way of generating the correct amount of text fields based on the number selected
    getNumPlayers = async () => {
        let players = await AsyncStorage.getItem('Num_Players');
        this.setState({number_players: players});

        var players_json_middle = '';
        var x;
        for (x = 1; x <= players; x++) {
            player = '{"Player": "Player ';
            num_str = x.toString();
            if (x != players) {
                var player_num = player.concat(num_str, '"},');
            } else {
                var player_num = player.concat(num_str, '"}');
            }
            players_json_middle = players_json_middle.concat(player_num);
        }
        var players_json_start = '{"Players":[';
        var players_json_end = ']}';
        var players_json_str = players_json_start.concat(players_json_middle, players_json_end);
        var players_json = JSON.parse(players_json_str);
        this.setState({num_players: players_json.Players});
    }

    renderItem = ({item}) => {
        return (
            <TextField
                placeholder={item.Player}
                //This is my main problem. It isn't the way to change the state of the player names.
                onChangeText={() => this.setState(item.Player)}
            />
        )
    }
    
    signUp = async () => {
        let user = await AsyncStorage.getItem('email');

        const {Player1} = this.state;
        const {Player2} = this.state;
        const {Player3} = this.state;
        const {Player4} = this.state;
        const {Player5} = this.state;
        const {Player6} = this.state;
        const {Player7} = this.state;
        const {Player8} = this.state;
        
        fetch('fetch address is here [this isn't the problem]', {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application.json',
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({
                email: user,
                player1: Player1,
                player2: Player2,
                player3: Player3,
                player4: Player4,
                player5: Player5,
                player6: Player6,
                player7: Player7,
                player8: Player8
            })
        }).then((response) => response.json())
        .then((responseJson) => {
            this.props.navigation.navigate('round_start_screen');
        }).catch((error) => {
            console.error(error);
        });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <ScrollView>
                <View style={{alignItems: 'center'}}>
                    <Text style={styles.headingText}>
                        Game Name
                    </Text>
                </View>
                <View style={styles.container}>
                    <Text style={styles.text}>
                        What are the players' names?
                    </Text>
                    <View style={{width: '80%'}}>
                    //Rendering the flatlist here
                        <FlatList
                            data={this.state.num_players}
                            renderItem={this.renderItem}
                            keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
                        />
                    </View>
                    <PrimaryButton
                        onPress={() => this.signUp()}
                        label="Start Game"
                    >
                    </PrimaryButton>
                </View>
            </ScrollView>
        );
    }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        alignItems: 'center',
        backgroundColor: colors.backgroundColor,
        margin: 10,
        paddingBottom: 5,
        borderWidth: 1,
        borderColor: colors.borderColor,
    },
    text: {
        fontSize: 24,
        color: colors.primaryText,
        marginTop: 10,
    },
    headingText: {
        fontSize: 24,
        fontWeight: '500',
        color: colors.primaryText,
        margin: 10,
    },
})

export default player_names_screen;
```

Is there a way to be able to name the players here and store them? Or is this whole approach an exercise in futility? Is there a much better way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You havent provided a key to update. You also need to use the text value that changed.

```
renderItem = ({item, index}) => {
    return (
        <TextField
            placeholder={item.Player}
            onChangeText={(newText) => this.setState({[`Player${index}`]: newText})
        />
    )
}
```

You might want to consider using an array for this state though. It would enable you to update the array at the index position, instead of doing string interpolation.

Comment: I'm not getting the error message anymore, but the states are not changing.

Comment: I got it to work. I had to add an "id" to the JSON that I was storing in num_players. But now I know about string interpolation. Thank you.

Comment: @W.Robarts my bad, it should be index not id. It´s appended to the list item by the FlatList component. I have edited the answer to reflect this.

Answer (score 0):

If you need a fast solution, you can add a switch case as follows,

```
renderItem = ({item, index}) => {
        return (
            <TextField
                placeholder={item.Player}
                onChangeText={() => this._updateState(item, index)}
            />
        )
    }

_updateState = (item, index) => {
 switch(index) {
  case 0: this.setState({Player1 :item.Player}); break;
  case 1: this.setState({Player2 :item.Player}); break;
  case 2: this.setState({Player3 :item.Player}); break;
  case 3: this.setState({Player4 :item.Player}); break;
  case 4: this.setState({Player5 :item.Player}); break;
  case 5: this.setState({Player6 :item.Player}); break;
  case 6: this.setState({Player7 :item.Player}); break;
  case 7: this.setState({Player8 :item.Player}); break
 }
}
```

Comment: Visual Studio Code is giving a syntax error at the colons just before "item.Player"